# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I keep getting this annoying error, no clue how to solve it.

I'm trying to open a txt file with a for statement:

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1
```

Comment: `for i, l in enumerate(f)` creates a new scope with variables `i, l` which are not defined in outer-scopes.

Comment: I suspect you're getting downvoted because the error message is a literally perfect description of what you're doing wrong

Comment: @клйкбаутоьмажазвайкукас incorrect, for-loops *do not have their own scope*. Theproblem here, I suspect, is that `enumerate(f)` is empty, thus `i` and `l` never get assigned to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is what you need:

```
def file_len(fname):
    counter = 0
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

A more elegant version of it:

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        length = len(f.readlines())
    return length
```

Answer (score 3):

Your file is empty. No iterations of the loop run, and `i` is never assigned.

You'll need to handle the empty-file case. For counting items in an iterable that doesn't support `len`, I usually go with `sum(1 for elem in thing)`:

```
def file_line_count(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        return sum(1 for line in f)
```